# SharedPreferences issue, overwritting

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have some values stored in a shared preference file and at some point on my code, I split this file and upload the shares to several clouds so that i can have a secure backup.

So my app now, when it's starting takes a look at the shared preferences folder and if this file doesn't exist, it asks the user to log in the clouds to recover the file (think of the case a user loses its cellphone).

So, trying the performance, I simulate I don't have such file and download the parts and combine them to get the whole. The file is recovered perfectly (I manually open it and it has all the fields).

However, when I try to write new values in this file, the system doesn't recognize it, delete it and create a new one. All in all, the file is overwritten. Even if I try to read a value from the old file (the one I downloaded) it doesn't work and returns the default value.

Do you know what could be the problem and if there could be any solution apart from not using Shared Preferences?

```
KeyManagement.combineFile(split);
SharedPreferences prefs = mContext.getSharedPreferences("CACSPrefs", 0);
String key = prefs.getString("KEY", null);
Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putString("IS_STORED", "TRUE");
editor.commit();
```

split is an array of Files (the parts I download from the Internet). I've checked the recombined file is called "CACSPrefs.xml"

**EDIT**

When I split the original file, I go one by one sending one byte to each of the shares, each of one is called with the same name but adding "_1", "_2", ... So combine file behaves the other way round.

```
protected static void combineFile(File[] fileShares) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{

    // create file
    String parentPath = fileShares[0].getParent();
    String fileName = fileShares[0].getName().substring(0,
            fileShares[0].getName().indexOf("_"));
    File file = new File(parentPath + "/" + fileName);  
    if (!file.exists()) file.createNewFile();
    FileInputStream[] in = new FileInputStream[fileShares.length];

    // create input streams
    int length = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < fileShares.length; i++){
        length += (int) fileShares[i].length();
        in[i] = new FileInputStream(fileShares[i].getAbsolutePath());
    }       

    // read byte by byte and write
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);  
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++){
        int b;
        if((b = in[i % fileShares.length].read()) == -1) break;
        out.write((byte) b);
    }
    out.flush();
    out.close();

    for (int i = 0; i < fileShares.length; i++){
        in[i].close();
    }
}
```

Comment: try editor.apply() instead of editor.commit()

Comment: same result. The problem is the system doesn't recognize the file. In the code, the String key is returned as null.

Comment: may I see combineFile function?

Comment: sure! it's at the end, I've editted the question

Comment: Its not possible to replace the file, however you could just update the values, I understand you get different types to look out for but its only what i can think of

Comment: btw the suggested JSON uploading is a better suggestion, you can use Gson for serialization and deserialization also

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest another solution. Write a method to transform only the values you want to upload to cloud to JSON using standard `SharedPreferences.get*()` methods and upload the JSON. Then when you need it back you get the JSON, read the values and store it again using the standard `SharedPreferences.Editor.put*(...)` methods.

You avoid any errors your original code may have introduced which caused the `SharedPreferences` to not recognize the file (or not use it to load values), because you're using the official way of accessing shared preferences.

**EDIT:** Or don't use JSON, you can use any transport protocol you like, even your own, as long as you write the preferences the way described above.

**EDIT 2:** As OP requested here comes an example of how to get selected shared preferences as JSON and vice versa.

To get some shared preferences into a JSON object do the following:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("my_prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

try {
  json.put("my_long", prefs.getLong("my_long", 0));
  json.put("my_string", prefs.getString("my_string", null));
  // only upload this one if it's set
  if (prefs.contains("my_boolean")) json.put("my_boolean", prefs.getBoolean("my_boolean", false));
} catch (JSONException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}

String toUpload = json.toString();
```

Now upload the `String toUpload` e.g. as a POST request body.

To save shared preferences obtained from server do the following:

```
String fromDownload =...; // obtained from http response body

try {
  SharedPreferences prefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("my_prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
  JSONObject json = new JSONObject(fromDownload);

  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
  // this will throw JSONException if no value came from server
  editor.putLong("my_long", json.getInt("my_long"));
  // this will set a default value if no value came from server
  editor.putString("my_string", json.optString("my_string", "default"));
  // this will only store the value if it came from server otherwise no-op
  if (json.has("my_boolean")) editor.putBoolean("my_boolean", json.getBoolean("my_boolean"));
  editor.apply();
} catch (JSONException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: i've never used that. could you show me a snippet of code?

Comment: The conversion of some `SharedPreferences` to JSON?

Comment: yeah that's what i mean. After getting all the string I want to save (a, b, c and d), what's the next step?